# error when using sendmailR to send email

Tags: r, sendmailr

I want to use `sendmailR` send email via `smtp.exmail.qq.com` server,I looked at the sample to do it ,but failed,how can I work it out?

```
sendmail(
      from="***@companyName.com",
      to="***@companyName.com",
      body="Hallo",   
      subject="from R procedure",
      control=list(smtpServer="smtp.exmail.qq.com"),
    )

Error in socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) :
  localhost:25 cannot be opened
```

Comment: Odd. You specify a server but it seems to be connecting to localhost. What do you get if you add `verbose=TRUE` to your control options? Please try, and then edit your question with the result...

Comment: I add `verbose=TRUE` as what you said,but error happened else.

    `Error in wait_for(code) : SMTP Error: Error: need EHLO and AUTH first !`